# How to automate export of schema and uploading it to S3 bucket and deleting the old dumps in AWS oracle RDS

Tags: amazon-s3

```
I am doing it manually as export , uploading it to s3 bucket and deleting the old dumps.
```

Someone help to automate it

1)script to export the schema ICO_AV_PRD_OWR

```
    DECLARE
    hdnl NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null, 
    version=>12);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'dump.dmp', directory => 
   'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'dump.log', directory => 
    'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_log_file);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''schemaname'')');
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
    END;
    /
```

2)copy the dump to S3 bucket

```
    set lines 399 pages 999
    col filename for a45
    select * from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) order by mtime; --- 
    listing the files

    SELECT rdsadmin.rdsadmin_s3_tasks.upload_to_s3(
    p_bucket_name    =>  'bucketname',
    p_directory_name =>  'DATA_PUMP_DIR') 
    AS TASK_ID FROM DUAL;
```

3)Remove the dumps from RDS
exec utl_file.fremove('DATA_PUMP_DIR','dump.dmp');
exec utl_file.fremove('DATA_PUMP_DIR','dump.log');

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda function scheduled to run depending on an event generated by CloudWatch. The Lambda function is initiated at the scheduled interval by using Amazon CloudWatch Events, that will run the query that you have mentioned in your question.

To write the lambda function you can use language of your choices say Python.

you can use date-time in p_s3_prefix to maintain the files in S3. That will help you to delete older files, say dump files that were uploaded 3 days back.

```
SELECT rdsadmin.rdsadmin_s3_tasks.upload_to_s3(
      p_bucket_name    =>  'mys3bucket', 
      p_prefix         =>  '', 
      p_s3_prefix      =>  'date-time/', 
      p_directory_name =>  'DATA_PUMP_DIR') 
   AS TASK_ID FROM DUAL;
```

Set your logic to replace the 'date-time' to actual date-time

You can see step by step guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/schedule-jobs-for-amazon-rds-and-aurora-postgresql-using-lambda-and-secrets-manager.html) as suggested by AWS.

Comment: this portion only helps on uploading and deleting the older dumps